# Vuex init state overrides changes in mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a variable in my store, I change it in a mounted property (through an action and a mutation), but it goes back to the initial value from the store.

(I tried with a button in the html, changing the variable works fine there.)

**Inside my component you can find :**

```
<template>
  <div id="stuff">
    <h1> some random word: {{ hola }}</h1> <-------- problem is here: it prints always ONE instead of THREE)
    <button @click="UPDATE_HOLA('carlos')" text="clickkkBTN"/>
  </div>
</template>

...
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['setHola']),
    ...mapMutations(['UPDATE_HOLA']),
  },
computed: {
    ...mapState(['hola']),
},
watch: {
    hola(newVal){
      console.log('watch' + newVal)
    }
},
mounted() {
    console.log(this.hola); //prints "ONE" (initial value in store)
    this.setHola('TWO');
    console.log(this.hola); //prints "TWO" 
    this.UPDATE_HOLA('THREE');
    console.log(this.hola); //prints "THREE" 
}
```

The **problem** is : in my console I have the following : ONE, TWO, THREE, watchTHREE, watchONE.

It goes back to ONE, the intial value in the store (I can see THREE for half a second, then it goes back to ONE)

My question is : why is the initial value coming back ? I must be doing something wrong. And is it possible to make the value THREE stay ?

**store/index.js :**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    hola: 'ONE',
  },
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
});
```

**in store/mutation.js :**

```
  [types.UPDATE_HOLA](state, payload) {
    state.hola = payload;
  },
```

**store/action.js**

```
const setHola = ({ commit }, payload) => {
  commit(types.UPDATE_HOLA, payload);
};

export default {
  setHola
}
```